# I need to create a mosaic using the loop programming construct with 16 tiles of the same pattern and three or more different colors using python

Tags: python, python-turtle

For my assignment i have to create a shape using turtle, then turn that shape into a mosaic with 16 tiles in a 4 * 4 pattern. I created the turtle shape but every attempt I've made to make a mosaic has ended in an error or no output. Here is my turtle shape i'm using for this project. How would I create a mosaic using this shape?

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('white')
wn.setup(500,500)
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.speed(10)
bob.pensize(2)
bob.color('purple')
for i in range(20):
    bob.left(140)
    bob.forward(100)
bob.hideturtle()
```

Comment: Can you describe what you would want your mosaic to look like? Do you want it to be 16 squares in a grid? If so, why are you rotating 20 times (and not 64)?

Comment: The mosaic I originally attempted to have was just my shape, recreated 4 times in 4 rows, totaling 16 shapes. I am open to suggestions on how to get there.

Comment: 4 wide, 4 tall of just my shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No output" probably means that the window is closing itself. Try adding this to the end to prevent that:

```py
# ...
bob.hideturtle()
input('press enter to exit')
```

---

You can draw the same shape multiple times by teleporting to the spot that you want each shape to be drawn.

```py
def shape():
    for i in range(18):
        bob.left(140)
        bob.forward(100)

# coordinates of each of the shapes
# these are completely arbitrary
# you can change these to whatever (adjust spacing, change where they are, etc)
# you can also write this using ranges if you want
for x in (-100, 0, 100, 200):
    for y in (-150, -50, 50, 150):
        bob.penup()
        bob.setposition(x, y)
        bob.pendown()
        shape()
```

This will loop through all 16 points, `-100, -150`, `-100, -50`, `-100, 50`, ..., `200, 150`.

Note that I changed your shape to only looping 18 times - this makes a total rotation of a multiple of 360 degrees so the next shape is not slanted. Additionally, the shape would only have 18 of these edges, so drawing the extra 2 would be a waste. [This is what would happen if it was left at 20.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z12l5.png)

---

Output:

[image]